# Struts2 JSON interceptor not populating my Action class

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am working on a web app in which the client JavaScript library (ExtJS) sends requests to my Struts-enabled backend with a JSON request payload.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the variables from the payload into my Action class.

I know from using log statements that the correct method in my action class is being called by the frontend.  It's just that the variables I am expecting are `null` when they shouldn't be.

I'm trying to use `struts2-json-plugin` as an interceptor.  Struts interceptors are new to me, and I haven't been able to find any clear examples on the web about using `struts2-json-plugin` in this way.

Here are the Struts dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the request body (care of Firebug):

```
{"id":15,"translation":"Blah blah"}
```

The relevant parts of my Action class look like this:

```
public class TranslationsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Long id;
    private String translation;

    public String save() throws Exception {

        log.debug("TranslationsAction.save() called.");
        log.debug("ID: " + this.id + ", Translation: " + this.translation);

        return "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

}
```

Here are relevant parts of my `struts.xml`:

```
<package name="foo" namespace="/foobar" extends="json-default">    
    <action name="save-translation" method="save"
            class="my.package.name.action.TranslationsAction">
        <result name="success">/jsp/json.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem myself.  I had failed to configure `struts.xml` properly.  I needed to first define an interceptor within my package, and then tell my action to use it, as in:

```
<package name="foo" namespace="/foobar" extends="json-default">    

    <!-- Added this: -->
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
    </interceptors>

    <action name="save-translation" method="save"
            class="my.package.name.action.TranslationsAction">

        <!-- And added this: -->
        <interceptor-ref name="myDefaultInterceptorStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="json" />

        <result name="success">/jsp/json.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

It was a silly omission on my part.  :-\

Comment: This will *only* run the JSON interceptor, which *may* be okay, but it's unlikely. Setting your default interceptor stack to `"jsonValidationWorkflowStack"` would be more correct for most usecases.

Comment: Thanks Dave for catching that.  I had discovered that in researching the above solution, but in my effort to simplify the solution for SO readers, I neglected to mention it.  I also added an <interceptor-ref /> tag for the default interceptor stack that the (legacy) codebase I'm working with is using.

Comment: Added reference to myDefaultInterceptorStack for clarity.

Comment: What does the `myDefaultInterceptorStack` consists of?

Comment: Adding `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>` in place of `<interceptor-ref name="myDefaultInterceptorStack" />` along with `<interceptor-ref name="json" />` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well JSON plugin require some steps to follow in order to work properly and here are few of them

1. The "content-type" must be "application/json".
2. The JSON content must be well formed, see json.org for grammar.

Its better if you could paste the relevant part of the JS (ExtJS) from where you are calling your Action class and sending the data to your action class.

Please have a look at the official JSON plugin Page for details

[json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks Umesh.  I found the problem, which I just posted as a separate answer.  It was a struts.xml error.