# Struts2 JasonInterceptor Content type must be 'application/json' or 'application/json-rpc'

Tags: json, struts2, autocomplete

Can anyone enlighten me in what scenarios I would get the following error in the log?

> Struts2 JasonInterceptor Content type must be 'application/json' or 'application/json->   rpc'. Ignoring request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I also notice that in the IE it shows a debug message as follows(not sure if these 2 messages are related):

> DEBUG:  please consider using a mimetype of text/json-comment-filtered to avoid potential >security issues with JSON endpoints
>   DEBUG:  [SyntaxError: Syntax error]

I specifically changed my s:form enctype attribute as follows and still couldnt get rid of this message:

```
<s:form id="dealerForm" action="AjaxAutocompleterAction" 
enctype="text/json-comment-filtered">
</s:form>
```

and this as well (didnt work again)

```
<s:form id="dealerForm" action="AjaxAutocompleterAction" 
enctype="application/json">
</s:form>
```

any ideas?

****************************Update - 1************************************

More information about the code I am working with follows:

My **AjaxAutocompleter.jsp** containing the linked autocompleters:

```
<s:form id="dealerForm" action="AjaxAutocompleterAction"
enctype="text/json-comment-filtered">
<sx:autocompleter id="dealer" name="dealer" searchType="substring"
    label="Dealer" list="dealerList" listKey="name" listValue="name"
    showDownArrow="false" valueNotifyTopics="/notifyBranch"
    errorNotifyTopics="/error" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    forceValidOption="true" loadMinimumCount="3" />
<sx:autocompleter id="branch" name="branch" searchType="substring"
    label="Branch" list="branchList" showDownArrow="false"
    listenTopics="/notifyBranch" formId="dealerForm"
    formFilter="function(paramName){return true;}"
    valueNotifyTopics="/notifyRep" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    afterNotifyTopics="/after" forceValidOption="true"
    loadMinimumCount="0" loadMinimumCount="3" />
<sx:autocompleter id="representative" name="representative"
    searchType="substring" label="Rep" list="repList"
    showDownArrow="false" forceValidOption="true" loadMinimumCount="0"
    formId="dealerForm" formFilter="function(paramName){return true;}"
    listenTopics="/notifyRep" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    afterNotifyTopics="/after" loadMinimumCount="3" />
<textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea" rows="25" cols="190"></textarea>
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default">
    <action name="AjaxAutocompleterAction" class="com.frk.gid.action.AjaxAutocompleterAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="ordered">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
        <result type="json" />
        <result name="success">/AjaxAutocompleter.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**my model classes**

```
public class Representative {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Branch {
    private String name;
    private List<Representative> representatives;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setRepresentatives(List<Representative> representatives) {
        this.representatives = representatives;
    }

    public List<Representative> getRepresentatives() {
        return representatives;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Dealer {
    private String name;
    private List<Branch> branches;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setBranches(List<Branch> branches) {
        this.branches = branches;
    }

    public List<Branch> getBranches() {
        return branches;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**my prepare method**

```
@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Prepare Started ...");
    ServletActionContext.getResponse().setContentType(
            "text/json-comment-filtered");
    dealerList = new ArrayList<Dealer>();
    int branchCounter = 0;
    int repCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Dealer d = new Dealer();
        List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            Branch b = new Branch();
            b.setName("BRANCH-" + branchCounter++);
            List<Representative> representatives = new ArrayList<Representative>();
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                Representative rep = new Representative();
                rep.setName("REP-" + repCounter++);
                representatives.add(rep);
            }
            b.setRepresentatives(representatives);
            branches.add(b);
        }
        d.setName("DEALER-" + i);
        d.setBranches(branches);
        dealerList.add(d);
        if (this.dealer == null && i == 0) {
            setDealer(d.getName());
        }

        // Populate DBR Hierarchy for the selected dealer.
        if (this.dealer != null && this.dealer.equals(d.getName())) {
            branchList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int bCount = 0;
            for (Branch b : branches) {
                branchList.add(b.getName());
                if (this.branch == null && bCount++ == 0) {
                    setBranch(b.getName());
                }
                if (this.branch != null && this.branch.equals(b.getName())) {
                    repList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (Representative r : b.getRepresentatives()) {
                        repList.add(r.getName());
                    }
                    if ((this.representative == null && repList.size() > 0)
                            || (this.representative != null && !repList
                                    .contains(this.representative))) {
                        setRepresentative(repList.get(0));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you describe what exactly you doing?

Comment: I am trying a struts2 **linked** autocompleter - where upon selection of a value in the autocompleter1, values get refreshed in autocompleter2. There are some exaxmples available in the net, however couldnt get them to work because of this issue described above.

Comment: not sure why you doing such heavy lifting in prepare method and more over not sure about using the json interceptor ref stack while same can be used in easy way.Please refer to this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886713/struts2-json-interceptor-not-populating-my-action-class

Comment: thanks for your response. it is not such heavy lifting actually - all i am doing there is generating data for 3 lists which are related to each other (which are essentially my autocompleter lists). I had already looked at this link you provided earlier - unfortunately it doesnt help my problem exactly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. finally after much struggle, I did manage to solve this myself . the clue lies in my autocompleter definition where I had to use dataFieldName always whenever I used the href.

Also, I couldnt get to load the first level hierarchy (in my case Dealer) to work with the href -i had to explicitly call the action and use the local variable.

I am posting my modified code so it could come in handy for other learners :-) Have fun !!!

**My Updated jsp**

```
<s:url id="dbrList" action="AjaxAutocompleterAction" 
encode="text/json-comment-filtered"/>
<s:action name="AjaxAutocompleterAction" id="myDBRAction" />
<sx:autocompleter id="dealerList" name="dealer" searchType="substring"
    label="Dealer" showDownArrow="false" valueNotifyTopics="/notifyBranch"
    errorNotifyTopics="/error" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    forceValidOption="true" loadMinimumCount="1"
    list="%{#myDBRAction.dealerList}" />

<sx:autocompleter id="branchList" name="branch" searchType="substring"
    label="Branch" list="branchList" showDownArrow="false"
    listenTopics="/notifyBranch" formId="dealerForm"
    formFilter="function(paramName){return true;}"
    valueNotifyTopics="/notifyRep" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    afterNotifyTopics="/after" errorNotifyTopics="/error"
    forceValidOption="true" loadMinimumCount="1" href="%{dbrList}"
    list="branchList" dataFieldName="branchList" />
<sx:autocompleter id="repList" name="representative"
    searchType="substring" label="Rep" list="repList"
    showDownArrow="false" forceValidOption="true" formId="dealerForm"
    formFilter="function(paramName){return true;}"
    listenTopics="/notifyRep" beforeNotifyTopics="/before"
    errorNotifyTopics="/error" afterNotifyTopics="/after"
    loadMinimumCount="1" href="%{dbrList}" dataFieldName="repList" />
```

**My updated struts.xml**

```
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json"     class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="AjaxAutocompleterAction" class="com.frk.gid.action.AjaxAutocompleterAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation" />
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="ordered">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
        <result name="success" type="json">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```